# Using cmd batch to find all the file with the same filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

For example, in a directory, I have N .eps files named `name1.eps, name2.eps, ...` and also much more pdf files. But within these pdf files, there are exactly N pdf files with the same filename as eps files, that is `name1.pdf, name2.pdf,...`.

So I want a batch that can scan the current dir, give a list of all eps files and corresponding list of pdf files.

finally I want another batch named `convert.bat` which takes two parameters to run a series of command as below

```
convert.bat name1.eps name1.pdf
convert.bat name2.eps name2.pdf
.....
.....
```

the `convert.bat` first compares the modified time of name.eps and name.pdf, and if the modified time of name.eps is newer than name.pdf, then it will run `epstopdf name.eps`, otherwise it will do nothing.

I am really a newbie in using cmd batch. could somebody teach me how to realize the whole process I mentioned above. Thank you so much!

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %G in ('dir /b files\*.eps') do @if exist "%~dpnG.pdf" @echo "%~fG" "%~dpnG.pdf"` is my initial hint. [Learn more](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html). Then, if necessary, [edit] your question, paste your script(s) and feel free to ask more... Or,  instead: if you get a solution, follow [answer] your own question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out a way. The following batch file do the whole job.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%G in (*.eps) do @if not exist "%%~nG.pdf" (epstopdf "%%G") else (
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /B /O:D "%%G" "%%~nG.pdf"') do set newest=%%~xi) & (
if !newest!==.eps epstopdf "%%G"))
```